# Convert cx_Oracle.LOB data to string in python

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
['ThisText', <cx_Oracle.LOB object at 0x02FDC080>]
```

Lst[1] content :

```
This is a string but as clob
```

Im populating the list from this query result as such :

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('mario.connex.ro', '1529', service_name='EAIUAT')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'LOGGING_DB05', password='passw0rd', dsn=dsn_tns)

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("select column1, column2 from DB_Table where column3 = '1234'")

lst = []


for i in c:
    for j in i:
        lst.append(j)
```

table structure is :

```
Column1 = varchar
Column2 = clob
Column3 = varchar
```

I want to convert the clob value from lst[1] to string

```
str = ''.join(lst[1])
```

Error received :

```
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Printed the lst[1] type :

```
print(type(lst[1]))
<class 'cx_Oracle.LOB'>
```

Is there a way to convert the cx_Oracle.LOB value to string?

Answer (score 7):

Solved : using cx.oracle.LOB.read() method to retrive LOB data.

```
str = ''.join(lst[3].read())
```

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, this involves extra server round-trips (per row) so probably better to have your connection/cursor request the string/bytes during that phase.

Answer (score 5):

Your own answer is a solution, but you should be aware that using the `.read()` method from the `cx.oracle.LOB` object will make some DB round trip at the time you call it, because this will stream your LOB content that might cause some performances issues.

If you want to minimize your DB round trip and your LOBs (CLOBs or BLOBs)  are smaller than 1GB you might directly obtain the LOB content as a string during the request using a `Cursor.outputtypehandler`

[Documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes) extract:

> Fetching LOBs as Strings and Bytes
>
> CLOBs and BLOBs smaller than 1 GB can queried from the database
> directly as strings and bytes. This can be much faster than streaming.
>
> A `Connection.outputtypehandler` or `Cursor.outputtypehandler` needs to be
> used as shown in this example:

```
def output_type_handler(cursor, name, default_type, size, precision, scale):
    if default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_LONG, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_BLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

id_val = 1
text_data = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
binary_data = b"Some binary data"
cursor.execute("insert into lob_tbl (id, c, b) values (:1, :2, :3)", [id_val, text_data, binary_data])

connection.outputtypehandler = output_type_handler
cursor.execute("select c, b from lob_tbl where id = :1", [id_val]) 
clob_data, blob_data = cursor.fetchone()
print("CLOB length:", len(clob_data)) print("CLOB data:", clob_data)
print("BLOB length:", len(blob_data)) print("BLOB data:", blob_data)
```

Comment: In successor library there is configuration to fetch lobs eagerly: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/defaults.html#api-defaults-object

Comment: @svobol13 you are linking to the old package not the "successor library" :|. As stated on the introduction page "The python-oracledb driver is the renamed, major version successor to cx_Oracle 8.3. For upgrade information, see Upgrading from cx_Oracle 8.3 to python-oracledb.".